# Custom busy handler for Rails SQLite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord

I have a Rails/SQLite3 setup which is getting exceptions

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked):
```

Now I understand that SQLite3 cannot do parallel writes, I'd be happy if they were blocked until the other write was finished, so done serially, rather than raising. This is something to do with default SQLite3 handler in C falling foul of Ruby's GIL, apparently. The fix, according to [this post](http://nerdjusttyped.blogspot.com/2014/11/threaded-sqlite-access-and-ruby-sqlite.html), is to install one's own "busy handler" for the SQLite3 connection, and I have this code in a Rails initializer

```rb
# config/initializers/sqlite3.rb

if ActiveRecord::Base.connection.adapter_name == 'SQLite' then
  if raw_connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection then
    puts 'installing busy handler'
    raw_connection.busy_handler do |count|
      puts 'QUACK'
    end
    puts 'done'
  else
    raise RuntimeError 'no DB raw connection!'
  end
end
```

On starting Rails (Puma in the console) I get the expected

```
installing busy handler
done
```

but on running parallel requests I get the exception with no `QUACK`, i.e., it seems that my handler has not been called.  Is this a misunderstanding of the scope of initializers? Is there a "correct" way to get this handler installed?

(Obviously the real handler will not just say `QUACK`, but I find that my "real" handler has no effect so replace it by a debugging version.)

Comment: Why bother? Are you really going to be deploying your app with SQLite? https://12factor.net/dev-prod-parity

Comment: yes. we are going to deploy with sqlite. Its a rock solid database. except for this issue that i have seen

Comment: @chovy: I never found a solution to this, I ended up switching to Postgres.

Comment: So my issue turned out to be the Deno library not supporting WAL. https://sqlite.org/forum/forumpost/3a85d47b66